# My Activity can't finish when i press back button

Tags: android

My Activity has a DialogFragment.java

```
LoginFragment loginFragment = new LoginFragment();
loginFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), LoginFragment.class.getSimpleName());
```

My DialogFragment onCreateView method.java

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setCancelable(false);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: override the method `onBackPressed()` and inside that call `finish()` or if calling from the fragment, `getActivity().finish()`

Comment: it's not work for me.

Comment: post the snippet here

Comment: I hope you are overriding the method `onBackPressed()` in your activity and not fragment. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Back button is not working because you have set setCancelable(false).
The purpose of setCancelable(false) method is not allow back button to close the dialog.
To close the dialog you'll have to call dismiss() method.

More about setCancelable() method - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#setCancelable(boolean)

More about dismiss() method - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#dismiss()